# Which layers in neural networks have weights/biases and which don't?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I've heard several different varieties about setting up weights and biases in a neural network, and it's left me with a few questions:

Which layers use weights? (I've been told the input layer doesn't, are there others?)

Does each layer get a global bias (1 per layer)? Or does each individual neuron get its own bias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common textbook networks like a multilayer perceptron - each hidden layer and the output layer in a regressor, or up to the softmax, normalized output layer of a classifier, have weights.  Every node has a single bias.

Here's a paper that I find particularly helpful explaining the conceptual function of this arrangement:

http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/

Essentially, the combination of weights and biases allow the network to form intermediate representations that are arbitrary rotations, scales, and distortions (thanks to nonlinear activation functions) for previous layers, ultimately linearizing the relationship between input and output.

This arrangement can also be expressed by the simple linear-algebraic expression L2 = sigma(W L1 + B) where L1 and L2 are activation vectors of two adjacent layers, W is a weight matrix, B is a bias vector, and sigma is an activation function, which is somewhat mathematically and computationally appealing.

Comment: By single bias, do you mean different biases for each neuron, or a single global bias over the whole network? One explanation said that was true as well, so it also confused me...

Comment: Sorry @Iggy12345 - wasn't clear.  Each node has its own bias.  This allows the system to shift the node's input (weights*previous layer activation) to different positions on its own activation function, essentially to tune the non-linearity in the optimal position.

Comment: Okay, I know it's been awhile, but do the input nodes of the input layer also have biases? Just clarifying

Comment: @Iggy12345, the input "nodes" don't have biases as the hidden layers would.   In principle, your model would factor out any biases (since the network only cares about relative differences in a particular input).  In practice it's common, however, to normalize ones inputs so that they lie in a range of approximately -1 to 1.   This has two functions, it can help your network find a good optimum quickly, and it helps prevent loss of numerical precision in the calculation.  See "Data Preprocessing" here: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/.